# Eclipse project access

Tags: java, eclipse

Context: I am new to using Eclipse and this is causing a bit of problems which I haven't faced with other IDEs before.The issue is, on starting Eclipse, I need to specify a workspace, my question is how can I set the workspace as default and be able to run files that I have in a different folder or directory?

The default workspace:
C:\Users\IDEAPAD\eclipse-workspace
The Files I want to run are in:
C:\Users\IDEAPAD\Desktop\New Block chain\Blockchain-Healthcare-Security-System-master

This different folder when I try to open directly in Eclipse does some weird stuff that I do not know how to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If a project lies outside your workspace then you can import it to your eclipse workspace. So try this. Go to `File > Import > [Select Import Wizard]` Follow the wizard. I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: Generally (except for Gradle projects), just use _File > Open Projects from File System_ which is a shortcut for _File > Import...: General > Projects from Folder or Archive_.